# Convert dataframe to a numpy matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have dataframe of the form

```
user_id  item_id  rating
1          abc       5
1          abcd      3
2          abc       3
2          fgh       5
```

I want to convert it into a numpy matrix such as

```
# abc  abcd  fgh
[[5,    3,    0]  # user_id 1
[3,    0,    5]] # user_id 2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), cast to `int` and last convert to array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
arr = df.pivot('user_id', 'item_id', 'rating').fillna(0).astype(int).values
print (arr)
[[5 3 0]
 [3 0 5]]
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
arr = df.set_index(['user_id','item_id']).unstack(fill_value=0).values
print (arr)
[[5 3 0]
 [3 0 5]]
```